# Pandas: "ValueError: could not convert string to float: " (empty string)

Tags: python, pandas, replace

When trying to convert a Pandas Series to `float`, I get this error message. It refers to an empty string (" "), which is not a `np.nan`. Just an empty string.

I tried replacing " " by `np.nan`, but it doesn't do anything. I also tried replacing " " by "" but it also doesn't do anything.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, " ", 6], [7, 8, 9]]), 
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df.astype(float)
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:

**I want to replace these " " by NaN values, in a large dataframe.**

Comment: What float value are you expecting for `" "` ?

Comment: `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use df.replace() function to perform this operation

```
df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
```